# How to change the langage, and starting day of the week input?

Tags: html, google-chrome

On my first computer my **week input**

```
<input type="week" />
```

shows up like this :

[image]

but on my second computer it shows up like this :

[image]

What makes a week input change its langage, and how can I make sure that it starts with monday and not sunday ?

PS : I am using chrome, so as my client

PS2: the two screens are not from the same app

Comment: I think it's locale. In USA (in my knowledge) Sunday is considered start of the week. For me (Poland) it's Monday. You can also observe this when you choose another language for mobile OS. It's similar to `,` or `.` as decimal point.

Comment: but my both computers are working under french langage, and i put <html lang="fr-fr"> on both computers

Comment: So why is your first calendar in English?

Comment: yes that's my question why is it in english, I am sure i am missing something :s

Comment: i found out what was the prob !! it was the chrome langage, when i changed it to french, the week starts from monday, and it is french, thank you !

Answer (score 0):

The problem was my browser's default langage,

**The solution** is : add the langage you want, and make sure that the option "google chrome is displayed in this language" is activated

Answer (score 0):

I can confirm that by going settings>advanced>Languages and Input and changing languages to English(US) to English(UK) fixed the default calendar to start week on Monday